# How to index file names only in certain directory in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

I usually exclude cache and log directories from indexing in my projects but sometimes I want to quickly navigate to a log file.

Is there a way to keep log contents excluded from indexing but make it show up in "Navigate to file" popup?

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: You may bookmark the file (not a line in that while but actual file) and use that (Bookmark with Mnemonic) to quickly navigate there (especially if you will use `0`-`9` for mnemonic). Side note: if file will be deleted .. then bookmark will disappear as well .. so you better keep such file always present (e.g. empty it instead of deleting). P.S. This SHOULD work even with files in excluded folders (at very least it works during the same session based on my ovservations).